# PHP Mapper pattern for link tables

Tags: php, mysql, design-patterns, pdo, datamapper

I'm finally getting my head around using the Mapper design pattern to structure an object oriented system I'm building in PHP.

I have classes like `User`, and `Project`, each with corresponding MySQL tables (and Mapper classes eg `ProjectMapper`, `UserMapper`)

What I want to know, is how to approach link tables while using this pattern. I have another class `Invitation` which invites a `User` to work on a `Project`. (It's just a standard link table, with a `project_id` and a `user_id`).

Say I want to get a Collection of all the users assigned to a particular project, firstly, where should this function go? `ProjectMapper` class, `InvitationMapper` class?

And secondly. how can I make this neat and sensible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at this very interesting article - it helped me a lot when I was working on my own model, which should be efficient and easy to use:

http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/implementing.the.domain.model.entries.and.authors

The author explains how to build a reliable model in Zend Framework, but you can use his ideas also in other frameworks or just building your own model without any framework.

I recommend you also (if you are working with Zend) to skip the testing parts - the topic itself is very complex and the testing can be done, when you are done with your model.

Building my own model, I modified a few things, so if you will have further questions - you know - don't hesitate to ask them ;)

Comment: That's a pretty hefty article! I'm not using any framework but I'll definitely hunt for some transferable ideas in there. Thanks.

Comment: It took me few days to understand and implement this model, so I can only encourage you not to give up after few hours ;) When you are done with this aricle you will surely have few concrete questions - I'll be glad to answer them (if I will know the answer, of course)